# How can I group odd and even using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to use LINQ to group my odd and even numbers in two separate arrays.

```
 int[] randNum = randomNums(20, 1000, 1000);
 var oddEvnNums = from num in randNum
                  group ???
                  select new { odd = oddNums[], even = evnNums[]}


 int oddNum = oddEvnNums.odd[0];
 int evenNum = oddEvnNums.even[0];
```

Comment: Please clarify the question - are you interested in whether the *values* are odd or even, or the *indexes* are odd and even? A complete example with desired output would be useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just create a lookup with a key of `num & 1` (equivalent to `num % 2` for positive numbers, but sticking with 1 instead of -1 for negative numbers):

```
var lookup = randNum.ToLookup(num => num & 1);
var even = grouped[0].ToArray();
var odd = grouped[1].ToArray();
```

Note that a lookup will return an empty sequence if you ask for a key which doesn't have any entries, so you don't need to worry about whether or not there *are* odd and even numbers.

Alternatively, instead of grouping, you could just potentially go through the whole sequence twice:

```
var even = randNum.Where(num => (num & 1) == 0).ToArray();
var odd = randNum.Where(num => (num & 1) == 1).ToArray();
```

That only works if the sequence is the same both times (rather than being randomly generated each time you iterate, for example) but it may be more efficient than the grouping approach.

Comment: I'd favor the simple version at the end, the grouped versions may fail without further error handling because with random numbers, maybe there is no odd or even group.

Comment: @nvoigt: The lookup version would still work in that case - but it's a good point about the group version, which also has ordering issues. Will remove that.

Answer (score -1):

just group by the modulo

```
from num in randNum
group num by (num % 2) == 0
```

Comment: Well it wouldn't compile, for one thing... you'd need `group num by num % 2`.